# Use Xuggler to quicky segment file without decoding/encoding

Tags: encoding, playframework, http-live-streaming, xuggle

Writing a Java application using the Play framework and need some HTTP-Live streaming. I intent to segment the mp4 files on the fly, on-demand. I tried a c-segmenter for that (from Carson McDonald) and it is very quick. However, I like to integrate the code into my Java application for easier control so tried Xuggler.

However in this setup Xuggler seems to decode and recode the object, as running it takes some significant time (24 seconds runs in about 12 seconds on MacbookPro). Is there a way to run a similar code without it doing any heavy lifting, just to cut the file in segments?

While this is quite simple with a code like the test code below:

```
public static void segmentMediaFile (String sourceUrl) {
    Logger.debug("Starting segmenting process...");
    IMediaReader mediaReader = ToolFactory.makeReader(sourceUrl);

    MediaSegmenterListener listener = new MediaSegmenterListener();

    IMediaReader reader = ToolFactory.makeReader(sourceUrl);

    reader.addListener(listener);
    int count = 0;

    IMediaWriter currentWriter = makeMediaWriterFromCounter(++count, reader);
    reader.addListener(currentWriter);

    while (reader.readPacket() == null)
      do {
        if (listener.newFile()) {
           reader.removeListener(currentWriter);
           currentWriter.flush();
           currentWriter.close();
           currentWriter = makeMediaWriterFromCounter(++count, reader);
           reader.addListener(currentWriter);
        }
      } while(false);
}

private static IMediaWriter makeMediaWriterFromCounter (final int counter, IMediaReader reader) {
    String destinationUrl = "./public/testdata/test-movie/";
    return ToolFactory.makeWriter(destinationUrl + counter + "_some_name.mov", reader);
}
```

(The listener currently just makes the decision to create a new file according to the timestamp)

Or is this the wrong way of going about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the code based on IPacket , algo was something like
openOutput container set the streams for video and audio and then reads the packets from input container and write into outputContainer. 
Code is working fine without any exception etc. but only thing is i am unable to see pictures instead audio is working fine. 
let me know your id i will send you the code, may be you will figure out what is wrong in that.

Thanks

Comment: I got a working system myself, at least for the segmenting (using the Toolfactory and a MediaToolAdapter), am working on encoding with build in segmented at the moment.

Comment: If you don't mind can you share your code ? I hope you are not decoding the video.

Comment: I will try in the next few days. Have been on holidays for a week,

Answer (score 0):

I developed the following code to segment media files. However, as I needed encoding as well,

I never tested it (and don;'t have the version with encoding working yet), but it puts files out which seem correct from the outside. Maybe it will help somebody on the way. (defiantly would not trust the output .m3u8 file)

```
public static void segmentMediaFile (String sourceFile, String destinationDir, String extension) throws Exception {
    final int segmentSize = 10;
    int counter = 0;

    final IContainer input = IContainer.make();

    // open the input file
    if(!(new File(sourceFile).exists())) throw new Exception("Source file " + sourceFile + " does not exist!");
    input.open(sourceFile, IContainer.Type.READ,null);

    IContainer output = getOutputContainer(counter, input, destinationDir, extension);

    double lastNewFilePostion = 0;
    double currentFilePostion = 0;

    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(destinationDir + "prog_index.m3u8");
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    out.write( "#EXTM3U\n#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10\n#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0\n");
    out.close();

    for(;;)
    {
      final IPacket pkt = IPacket.make();
      if (input.readNextPacket(pkt) < 0)
            break;

      // Only needed to calculate the last segment size!
      currentFilePostion = pkt.getTimeStamp() * pkt.getTimeBase().getValue();

      if (((currentFilePostion - lastNewFilePostion) >= segmentSize) ||
              (pkt.isKeyPacket() && ((currentFilePostion - lastNewFilePostion) >= segmentSize - 0.5))){
           if(!((currentFilePostion - lastNewFilePostion) >= segmentSize)) Logger.debug("Keyframe overrulled segment at " + currentFilePostion);

           File filename = new File(output.getURL());
           int lastSegementLength = (int) (currentFilePostion - lastNewFilePostion);
           writeTrailer(output);

           fstream = new FileWriter(destinationDir + "prog_index.m3u8",true);
           out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
           out.write("#EXTINF:" + lastSegementLength + ",\n" + filename.getName() + "\n");
           out.close();

           counter++;
           output = getOutputContainer(counter, input, destinationDir, extension);

           lastNewFilePostion = currentFilePostion;
      }

      output.writePacket(pkt, false);
    }

    // Write the m3u8 file
    File filename = new File(output.getURL());
    int lastSegementLength = (int) (currentFilePostion - lastNewFilePostion);
    String segmentList = "#EXTINF:" + lastSegementLength + ",\n" + filename.getName() + "\n";
    segmentList = segmentList + "#EXT-X-ENDLIST\n";

    fstream = new FileWriter(destinationDir + "prog_index.m3u8",true);
    out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    out.write(segmentList);
    out.close();

    writeTrailer(output);
}


private static IContainer getOutputContainer (final int counter, IContainer input, String destinationDir, String extension) throws Exception {
    IContainer output = IContainer.make();
    output.open(destinationDir + "segment_" + counter + "." + extension, IContainer.Type.WRITE, null);

    int numStreams = input.getNumStreams();
    for(int i = 0; i < numStreams; i++)
    {
      final IStream stream = input.getStream(i);
      final IStreamCoder coder = stream.getStreamCoder();
      coder.open();

      IStreamCoder newCoder = IStreamCoder.make(IStreamCoder.Direction.ENCODING, coder);
        if(newCoder != null ){
          output.addNewStream(i);
          output.getStream(i).setStreamCoder(newCoder);
          newCoder.open();
      } else {
          Logger.warn("Is there an invalid stream present in video file: " + input.getURL() + "! IGNORING, but this might be serious");
      }


    }

    // write the output header
    writeHeader(output);

    return output;
}

private static void writeHeader(IContainer output){
    output.writeHeader();
}

private static void writeTrailer(IContainer output){
    // write the output trailers
    output.writeTrailer();
    int streams = output.getNumStreams();
    for(int j = 0; j < streams; j++)
    {
      output.getStream(j).getStreamCoder().close();
    }
    output.close();
}
```